# TabBar Hidden on iPad (Swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift

The TabBarItems do not show up on the iPad simulators (but do work on iPhone simulators).

I expect: [image]  but get:  [image]

How do I prevent this "shortcut bar" (if that is what it is) from appearing and/or covering the TabBar?  Can I do it in Storyboard?

On the other hand, I like the idea of having those undo, redo, and cut/paste buttons - is there a way to display that bar above or below my TabBar?

**UPDATE**:  Removing `inputField.becomeFirstResponder()` from `viewWillAppear` removes it (but causes other problems such as not being able to click back into the inputField if another field is clicked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This removes the shortcut bar:

```
inputField.inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups.removeAll()
inputField.inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups.removeAll()
```

But I would still love to know how to move the bar...